# CSS Hexagon with elements inside

Tags: html, css

I have a hexagon created by CSS. I am trying to get a header, paragraph and button inside the hexagon, but all of these elements are hiding behind the hexagon's before and after formatting. Here is a link to the code: https://jsfiddle.net/o8a3pm3h/6/ .
Any suggestions of how to place the elements on the surface of the hexagon div are appreciated.

```css
#hex3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#color3 {
  background-color: #CED7DC;
}
.hexagon-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.hexagon {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% * 0.57735);
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}
.hexagon:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: calc((100% / 2) - ((100% * 0.57735) / 2));
  background-color: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  content: '';
  transform: rotateZ(60deg);
}
.hexagon:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: calc((100% / 2) - ((100% * 0.57735) / 2));
  background-color: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  content: '';
  transform: rotateZ(-60deg);
}
```

```html
<!--Please maintain the styling here because its on top of an image-->
<div id="hex3" class="hexagon-wrapper" style="position:absolute; top:80px; right:400px;">
  <div id="color3" class="hexagon">
    <h4>TEST</h4>
    <p>TESTTTTTTTTTT</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="grid-row-btn-2" onclick="location.href='/#/'">
      DISCOVER MORE &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Also, I know that inline CSS is bad practice, but it is only for this demo.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/o8a3pm3h/7/  `.hexagon:before , .hexagon:after {
  z-index:-1;}` works fine too ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just wrap the content in a `div`, position it, and give it a `z-index`:

```
.content {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

[JSFiddle Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/32w7cerj/)

Comment: Perfect and simple. I'm a CSS newbie; will accept after time. Thank you

Comment: @sam_smith glad I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

You also need to position the text and set the z-index so that the text is above the other elements:

```
.hexagon h4, .hexagon p, .hexagon button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}
```

**Example**

```css
#hex3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
}
#color3 {
  background-color: #CED7DC;
}
.hexagon-wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}
.hexagon {
  height: 100%;
  width: calc(100% * 0.57735);
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 1;
}
.hexagon:before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: calc((100% / 2) - ((100% * 0.57735) / 2));
  background-color: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  content: '';
  transform: rotateZ(60deg);
}
.hexagon:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: calc((100% / 2) - ((100% * 0.57735) / 2));
  background-color: inherit;
  height: inherit;
  width: inherit;
  content: '';
  transform: rotateZ(-60deg);
}
.hexagon h4,
.hexagon p,
.hexagon button {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1
}
```

```html
<!--Please maintain the styling here because its on top of an image-->
<div id="hex3" class="hexagon-wrapper" style="position:absolute; top:80px; right:400px;">
  <div id="color3" class="hexagon">
    <h4>TEST</h4>
    <p>TESTTTTTTTTTT</p>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="grid-row-btn-2" onclick="location.href='/#/'">
      DISCOVER MORE &nbsp;<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
```